# Oracle connection does not work on second try

Tags: c#, oracle, dbconnection

```
public void comboboxes()
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=kursinis1;Password=1234;Unicode=True"))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            DataSet dsetas1 = new DataSet();
            OracleDataAdapter data1 = new OracleDataAdapter("select aut_id, (aut_vardas || ' ' || aut_pavarde) AS autorius from autoriai", conn);
            data1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            data1.Fill(dsetas1);
            dsetas1.Dispose();
            data1.Dispose();
            conn.Close();

            comboBox1.DataSource = dsetas1.Tables[0];
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "autorius";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "aut_id";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }
    }
}
```

When I call function first time, it works (fills data to the checkbox), but when I try to call the function a second time (by button click). It shows an error that my connection is not open:

**`Error: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource is set.`**

What is the problem?

Comment: What is the exact message in `ex.Message`?

Comment: could you do like this `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message +"  Can not open connection ! ");` so we can know the problem

Comment: why not put the try outside the `using` clause

Comment: Error: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource is set."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't even need to clear the `ComboBox.Items` property while using `DataBinding`.

Second, you're disposing both your `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` before binding the result set to your `ComboBox` control.

Third, the use of the `using` block defines the scope for which your variables shall be used, and outside which they shall be disposed automatically.

I commented out the lines you don't need and added a `finally` clause which gets executed anytime your `try...catch` block ends.

```
public void comboboxes() {
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=kursinis1;Password=1234;Unicode=True")) {
        try {
            conn.Open();
            //comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            DataSet dsetas1 = new DataSet();
            OracleDataAdapter data1 = new OracleDataAdapter("select aut_id, (aut_vardas || ' ' || aut_pavarde) AS autorius from autoriai", conn);
            data1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            data1.Fill(dsetas1);
            //dsetas1.Dispose();
            //data1.Dispose();
            //conn.Close();

            comboBox1.DataSource = dsetas1.Tables[0];
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "autorius";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "aut_id";
        } catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! "); }
        finally {
            if (ConnectionState.Open == conn.State) conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Should you wish to make sure both your `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` gets disposed as soon as they are no longer needed, put them in `using` blocks.

```
using (var cnx = new OracleConnection(connectionString)) 
    using (var ds = new DataSet())
        using (var da = new OracleDataAdapter(query)) {
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            if (ConnectionState.Closed == cnx.State) cnx.Open();

            da.Fill(ds);

            comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "autorius";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "aut_id";                                 
        }
```

All three: your connection, data set and data adapter will be disposed automatically when your code exits the `using` blocks.

Or else, if your prefer, you may as well surround your connection's openings in a `try...catch...finally` block, and make sure your connection gets closed whatever happens.

Furthermore, it is preferable if you let the exception bubble up your application in ordre to get the full stack trace and proper exception when it occurs, so that you get all the required details to solve your problem.

You `try...catch` exceptions when they are handled gracefully. Take logging, for instance, and then probably simply rethrown to you GUI so that you may handle it grafully with a proper error message and such.

Answer (score 1):

You are disposing the DataSet before you use it to bind to the comboBox.  The data set must have a lifetime equal to the comboBox.

You either need to make the DataSet a member of the class that owns the comboBox (and dispose when the class is disposed), or copy the data from the table into another table or object list that is a class member before disposing the DataSet, and bind to that object instead.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "autorius";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "aut_id";
    }

    public void comboboxes()
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=kursinis1;Password=1234;Unicode=True"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OracleDataAdapter data1 = new OracleDataAdapter("select aut_id, (aut_vardas || ' ' || aut_pavarde) AS autorius from autoriai", conn))
            {
                data1.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                data1.Fill(dataTable);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(not tested, but something like this)

Comment: Hard to understand, maybe you can show this in code (simple example).

Comment: I think the confusion is that the data binding does not make a copy of the data from the data table, it accesses the data from the table whenever the comoboBox is dropped down.  You use the Items property or data binding, not both.